# Rails on Azure VM (Ubuntu) not reachable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, port

I have hosted my Rails Application on an Azure VM running Ubuntu.
When I start the Webrick Dev Server with rails s, I get the console message that it is running.

But the app is not reachable under ip:3000

I configured an inbound security role for my vm nsg with these settings:
[image]

Can you please give me a hint where the problem could be?It is just a tryout. Not for production!

UPDATE:
results of netstat -ant-[image]

UPDATE 2:
[image]
[image]

Comment: which port does this application listen on? please use this command to check it `netstat -ant`

Comment: Please try to telnet port 3000 from outside?

Comment: "connection refused" - so I think my azure configuration is not right?

Comment: Maybe we should check the NSG settings, and ubuntu firewall settings, and subnet's NSG. there are something block it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, please follow this list to check it:

1.Please check Azure VM's NSG settings, make sure we have add port to inbound rules:
2.Vnet-->subnet's security group settings(by default is none): 
[image]
3.Check ubuntu firewall settings.

==========================
**Update**:

Your Rails listen on 127.0.0.1, you may modify it to 0.0.0.0

Comment: @mahu Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Everything is standard/out of the box. I just created the subnet "default" - but it does not matter if it is there or not. I can delete it and nothing else happens. Ubuntu ufw is disabled

Comment: Have you enable iptables?

Comment: Please wait for few mins, let me test it :)

Comment: it is a blank ubuntu 16.04 installation. I just installed ruby via rbenv, mysql and pulled my repo to test it -  I did nothing with iptables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145433/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-mahu).

Comment: @mahu Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.